# numpy vertical function :'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have a numpy arrary:

```
import numpy as np

pval=np.array([[0., 0.,0., 0., 0.,0., 0., 0.],
              [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0., 0., 0.]])
```

And a vectorized function:

```
def getnpx(age):
    return pval[0]+age
    
vgetnpx = np.frompyfunc(getnpx, 1, 1)

vgetnpx(1)
```

The output:

```
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

However if I want to set a variable for pval:

```
def getnpx(mt,age):
    return mt[0]+age

vgetnpx = np.frompyfunc(getnpx, 2, 1)

vgetnpx(pval,1)
```

I received an error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

What is the correct way to set a variable for pval ?Any friend can help?

Comment: You should inspect the value of `mt` being used in the function. When you pass the ufunc an array, it will call evaluate the function for each value in the array. For what you are doing, it's not clear why you are using `frompyfunc` rather than just making a regular function (i.e calling `getnpx(pval,1)`)

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,because I have very complicated logic on it,such as np.cumprod I have work this for 1 month I have to use frompyfunc

Comment: If you *have* to use `frompyfunc` then you should get to know [ufuncs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html) since that what it returns. The first sentence tells you they "operate...in an element-by-element fashion", which means they don't work for what you are trying to do unless you can pass in something that will be broadcast the way you want (like: `vgetnpx(pval,[[1], [0]])`) where the return value of the main func is just `mt+age`.

Comment: what did you expect `frompyfunc` to do with the `pval` array?

Comment: Thank you so much for asking @hpaulj please check this question and you will know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68955129/pandas-numpy-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-while-math-operation

Comment: @Mark thank you for asking,please check thsi question you will know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68955129/pandas-numpy-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-while-math-operation

Comment: In the link case `test` expects and gets single numbers.  Here your `getnpx` treats `mt` as an array, with indexing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you are trying to use `frompyfunc`.  That's for passing array arguments to a function that only takes scalar inputs.

```
In [97]: pval=np.array([[0., 0.,0., 0., 0.,0., 0., 0.],
    ...:               [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0., 0., 0.]])
```

In the first case you use global `pval`, and use just 1 `age` value.  No need to `frompyfunc`:

```
In [98]: pval[0]+1
Out[98]: array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

And if you want to pass `pval` as argument, just do:

```
In [99]: def foo(mt,age):
    ...:     return mt[0]+age
    ...: 
In [100]: foo(pval,1)
Out[100]: array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

You gave a link to an earlier question that I answered.  The sticky point in that case was that your function returned an array that could vary in size.  I showed how to use it with a list comprehension.  I also showed how to tweak `vectorize` so it would happy returning an `object` dtype result.  Alternatively use `frompyfunc` to return that object.  In all those cases the function argument was a scalar, a single number.

If your goal is to add a different `age` to each row of `pval`, just do:

```
In [102]: pval + np.array([[1],[2]])
Out[102]: 
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.]])
```